# Modify the rightclick menu options of cxgrid

Tags: delphi, devexpress, tcxgrid

In cxGrid,where do you modify the menu options when you right click in the Grid?

I would like to get rid of that "Right to left reading order","Show Unicode control characters","Insert Unicode control character","Open IME" and "Conversion". I dont need them at all.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the standard context menu of the Windows `EDIT` control, and not part of the Delphi code behind the control that you are using. In other words, the Delphi control that you are using is wrapping some system provided functionality.

I suppose that it would be possible to remove some items from that, but it's not easy. The `EDIT` control does not offer you any way to remove these built-in items. This issue has been discussed at the devExpress forum:

- https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q292288
- https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q102030